# klocwork error - Reference 'SchoolDataSet' checked for null at line 151 will be dereferenced at line 153

Tags: c#, klocwork

what could be the solution to resolve this Klocwork error,

> Reference 'SchoolDataSet' checked for null at line 151 will be dereferenced at line 153

```
if (SchoolDataSet == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException($"Cannot be casted to {SchoolDataSet .GetType().Name}.");
        }
```

Comment: Not very useful without the line numbers..

Comment: Noting you could use `"Cannot be casted to {nameof(SchoolDataSet)}."`